# What is the Hadamard product of matrix $A$ with $BC$, for $B, C$ being matrices?

Tags: matrices, hadamard-product

Say we have three matrices $A,B,C$. Define $\circ$ to be the Hadamard product. The usual matrix product of two matrices $B,C$ is denoted simply as $BC$. Is there an easy expression for
$$A\circ(BC)$$?

Answer (score 0):

$\def\D{\operatorname{Diag}}$Let $I$ be the identity matrix. Use the column vectors $(a_k,e_k)$ denote the $k^{th}$ columns of the matrices $(A,I),\,$ respectively. Then one can write the matrix $A$ as a sum of [dyadics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics#Dyadic_algebra)
$$A = \sum_{k=1}^n a_ke_k^T$$
The Hadamard product of a dyad and a matrix obeys
$$xy^T\circ M \;=\; \D(x)\cdot M\cdot\D(y)$$
Substituting into the given equation yields
$$\eqalign{
A\circ(BC) &= \sum_{k=1}^n a_ke_k\circ(BC) \\
 &= \sum_{k=1}^n \D(a_k)\;BC\,\D(e_k) \\
 &= \sum_{k=1}^n A_kBCE_k \\
}$$
where $A_k$ is a diagonal matrix constructed from the vector $a_k\,$ (and $E_k$ from $e_k$).